# How to get current library path

Tags: c++, linux

I have a plugin (`.so` file), that is dynamically loaded. In the same folder with the `.so` file I have some images. One function the plugin must implement is to return the paths of the images.

**How may I get the absolute path of the `.so` from itself in C++ (or C)?**

I know the issue can be solved easily from the executable (the images are in the same folder as the `.so`), but unfortunately I don't have access to its source code.

Comment: On Linux/glibc you can use `dl_iterate_phdr` in order to get most of the same information you have in `/proc/self/maps`, but without parsing anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Linux, `/proc/self/maps` will list the full path of every shared object currently loaded.  [Per the proc.5 man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html):

> ```
> /proc/[pid]/maps
> ```
>
> A file containing the currently mapped memory regions and their access permissions.  See mmap(2) for some further
>   information about memory mappings.
>
> ...
>
> The format of the file is:
>
> ```
>    address           perms offset  dev   inode       pathname
>    00400000-00452000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 173521      /usr/bin/dbus-daemon
>    00651000-00652000 r--p 00051000 08:02 173521      /usr/bin/dbus-daemon
>    00652000-00655000 rw-p 00052000 08:02 173521      /usr/bin/dbus-daemon
>    00e03000-00e24000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0           [heap]
>    00e24000-011f7000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0           [heap]
>    ...
>    35b1800000-35b1820000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 135522  /usr/lib64/ld-2.15.so
>    35b1a1f000-35b1a20000 r--p 0001f000 08:02 135522  /usr/lib64/ld-2.15.so
>    35b1a20000-35b1a21000 rw-p 00020000 08:02 135522  /usr/lib64/ld-2.15.so
>    35b1a21000-35b1a22000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
>    35b1c00000-35b1dac000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 135870  /usr/lib64/libc-2.15.so
>    35b1dac000-35b1fac000 ---p 001ac000 08:02 135870  /usr/lib64/libc-2.15.so
>    35b1fac000-35b1fb0000 r--p 001ac000 08:02 135870  /usr/lib64/libc-2.15.so
>    35b1fb0000-35b1fb2000 rw-p 001b0000 08:02 135870  /usr/lib64/libc-2.15.so
>    ...
>    f2c6ff8c000-7f2c7078c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0    [stack:986]
>    ...
>    7fffb2c0d000-7fffb2c2e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0   [stack]
>    7fffb2d48000-7fffb2d49000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0   [vdso]
> ```

If you know the base name of your shared object, you can parse the contents of /proc/self/maps and find the full path.

To guard against the name of the shared object being changed, you can also use the address of a symbol in your shared object to select the proper line from `/proc/self/maps`.

Comment: There's no need to use `dlsym` on your own shared object.

Comment: @n.m. Yeah, `dlsym()` works but you could just take the address of something.  I'll update.  Too early in the morning... ;-)